# TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

```
request = requests.get("http://api.roblox.com/Marketplace/ProductInfo?assetId=1834225941").content
print(str(request["Sales"]))
```

this gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yorks\Desktop\BloxUtility\bot.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(int(request["Sales"]))
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: the code in your example and in the error message is not fitting (`int()` vs `str()` casting) - please clarify!

Comment: _"byte indices must be integers or slices, not str"_ means that you did `a_bytes_object[a_str_object]` where only `a_bytes_object[an_int_object]` and your code has `request["Sales"]`, so obviously `request` is a `bytes` object, which means that it does not support `["Sales"]`.

Answer (score 31):

This should work

```
import requests
import json
request = requests.get("http://api.roblox.com/Marketplace/ProductInfo?assetId=1834225941").text
a = json.loads(request)
print(a['Sales'])
```

You can read up on deserializing [here](https://realpython.com/python-json/)

Answer (score 8):

I hope it can help you...

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("your_api_url")
if (response.status_code != 200):
    print("API is not working. status code :" + str(response.status_code))
else:
    print("API is working. status code :" + str(response.status_code))
    datas = json.loads(response.text)
    for value in datas['data']:
        print(value)
        #print(values['column_name'])
```

Answer (score 3):

as the content of the response is in JSON format, you should be able to access it with:

```
res = requests.get("http://api.roblox.com/Marketplace/ProductInfo?assetId=1834225941")
print(res.json()['Sales'])
```