# Django parsing json (from Webhooks)

Tags: python, json, django, webhooks, mailchimp

I am trying to parse some json received from Mailchimp to a Webhook in my Django application. The format will look like this:

```
{
  "type": "subscribe",
  "fired_at": "2009-03-26 21:35:57",
  "data": {
    "id": "8a25ff1d98",
    "list_id": "a6b5da1054",
    "email": "api@mailchimp.com",
    "email_type": "html",
    "ip_opt": "10.20.10.30",
    "ip_signup": "10.20.10.30",
    "merges": {
      "EMAIL": "api@mailchimp.com",
      "FNAME": "Mailchimp",
      "LNAME": "API",
      "INTERESTS": "Group1,Group2"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
def marketing_email_handler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

          reqtype = request.body['type']
          reqdata = request.body['data']
          reqemail = request.body['data']['email']
```

I received the error 'byte indices must be integers'.

I've tried changing this to the below, however this results in an error 'TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable'. And doing request.json() also results in an error

```
      reqtype = request.body[0]['type']
      reqdata = request.body[0]['data']
      reqemail = request.body[0]['data']['email']
```

I also tried (as suggested at [TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102398/typeerror-byte-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str))

```
json.loads(request.body)
```

but I receive the following: 'JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

Comment: What exactly is "an error"?

Comment: 1st how can you get Mailchimp data from Django **request**

Comment: json_data = json.loads(request.body)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102398/typeerror-byte-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

Comment: @iklinac - tried doing json.loads(request.body), but I receive the following: 'JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this - this issue was 'request.body' - this should instead have been request.POST